# How to kill Node process serving old site on localhost:8080 that does not exist on computer

Tags: node.js, macos, express, terminal

I have two node sites on my computer, both are started with `npm start` which runs ./bin/www and routes to localhost:8080.

Somehow, when I'm in the folder for site A and run `npm start`, site B is served on localhost. I've tried killing all node processes, deleting site B off of my computer, clearing the node cache, uninstalling and reinstalling node, and killing any processes running on port 8080 as evident by running `sudo lsof -i :8080`. The deleted, non-existent site is still showing on localhost:8080 even with node uninstalled. I deleted the site and emptied my trash just in case.

Any ideas? How do I kill this phantom process?

Additional info: I haven't ran site B in months. I don't know why two hours ago it decided it wanted to turn into a self-aware human-sanity-destroying virus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this! A service worker was running some cached version of this site in my browser... interestingly in all browsers. I unregistered the service worker and it's finally dead. I have no idea how it randomly spun up.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:
**ps -aux | grep '8080'**

then look for the process id and run:
kill {process_id}

It is also possible that the port is forwarded from a docker container if you use that so I would use a trace route to see where it end up.
Also make sure that it is not served from a network which is mounted or accessible as localhost.

Further I would need extra information, hard to guess...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up finding the partial cause. I had already tried this. Weirdly nothing showed up as running on that port.